# How to resize PowerPoint Objects and Text Proportionally at the same time?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I am trying to resize some textbox and shapes with texts in them in PowerPoint. and I cannot resize it proportionally. See the animated gif below for a demo.

Scenario: Let's say you are are working on a presentation slide which contains number of shapes/text/smartArts. And you would like to resize them to make it bigger or smaller. Currently, the only reasonable way I found is to copy them all first and paste it as an image. I can manually resize them one by one and also decrease/increase the font sizes. But there must be a better way to do this?

I did look up on MS support website and other places, but most of them are about resizing single/similar objects.

Here is the gif.

Thank you all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select them all, right-click a blank space in one of them then `Group`. You should then be able to resize them without them getting messed up. You will still need to increase or decrease the font size but that should be pretty easy to do when they are all selected by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (increase) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (decrease). You can then ungroup them later if need be.

Comment: it does not work. I grouped them and then when I resized to much smaller size, the texts went out of all the boxes. I am aware of doing this manually, I am seeking an answer to do it automatically. Thank you.

Comment: There's no way of automatically adjusting the font size when resizing shapes as far as I know but you can decrease font sizes by pressing `CTRL`+`[`, or increae by pressing `CTRL`+`]`

Comment: Great solution. However, note that not all objects can be grouped (notably, not placeholders, tables or worksheets): https://www.hungerford.tech/blog/powerpoints-grouping-feature-doesnt-always-work.php

Answer (score 1):

If only minimal editing afterward is needed, you can copy the shapes, choose Paste Special | as Enhanced Metafile.

When you resize the pasted metafile, the text will change size along with the shapes.

You might want to move the original group of shapes off the slide in case you need major edits later, or copy/paste it to another (hidden) slide.

Comment: Great idea. EMF file keeps the original resolution as I resize them. However, when I right click, the paste options are limited to `Use destination theme` and `Picture`. I understand that I can go to the ribbon to select `Paste Special` and pick `Enhanced Meta File`, but is there to add it to Right click `Paste Options`?

Comment: There might be with some VBA+ribbon code, but offhand, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve this:

1. Group all content.
2. Go to "Page Setup" and change the size of the slide by a factor of however much you want to scale (be sure to keep the same relative dimensions).
3. Click "Scale" when asked, and your objects (including font size) will be scaled proportionally.
4. If needed, you can resize the slide back to whatever size you need it to be, but click "Don't Scale" when prompted to not rescale the content.

Comment: I wish there was a better way than this, but this actually created the best result for me. Not perfect, some things may still jump around, but a lot better than the other options...